# Which organisations let general public to use any useful non confidential data or information by providing an xml?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb, pojo

I am working on self made project and that is coded in java. Right now I am using JAXB to parse xml data and mapping to a pojo. Next objective is to store data in a database. Creation of db tables according to the POJO is also part of my work.

My intention is to complete project that is meaningful to every other person who will be looking at my work. I decided to take some data (which is available in xml) and use it my project and give some visual (presenting on a Web Page) to it.

I am a self taught and my experience is less, hence I had to post this question. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about http://openweathermap.org/api? Data and the API is free and available to everyone. You can get the data as xml using the query-parameter "mode=xml"